# Wrap std::function to ignore parameters

Tags: c++, c++20, std-function

I am using a library:

```
// External Library:
typedef void (*callback_type)(void *arg);

void external_register_callback(callback_type callback, void* args) {
    // ...
}
```

It allows registering callback functions:

```
void example_callback_function(void *arg) {
    // do something with *arg.
}

external_register_callback(example_callback_function);
```

I need to write a wrapper layer for the library that will also allow registering a callback function, but instead of a function with `void*` parameter it is supposed to take a `std::function` with no parameters.
This is how my wrapper is supposed to look like:

```
void my_register_callback(std::function<void()> callback) {
    external_register_callback(... callback ...);  // how to "convert" callback to callback_type?
}
```

It is supposed to be used like this:

```
void my_callback_function() {
    // do something
}

void my_register_callback(my_callback_function);
```

**TL;DR:**

How to convert my `std::function<void()>` to a function-pointer that takes a `void*` argument but ignores it?

**Notes:**

I am using c++20.

The "conversion" of the function should (if possible) be done without runtime overhead. To be clear: I do not care about the runtime of `register_callback()`, but when the external library actually calls the callback, that should be fast.

**Edit:**

The `external_register_callback()` takes an additional `void*` argument that is passed to the callback, I added that to my code.

Comment: The API takes just a `void(*)(void*)` but... doesn't let you pass in a `void*` for the context? Does it pass _you_ some `void*`?

Comment: Please reply to @Barry's question. Doesn't `external_register_callback` also take a `void*` as input which is then later passed to the registered callback function?

Comment: @TedLyngmo And if I were a betting man...

Comment: @PaulSanders :-) Indeed. I don't think I've seen many C style callback registering functions that doesn't work like that.

Comment: It does indeed take a `void*` for the context, I will changed it in my question.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a proxy function and store a list of the `std::function<void()>`s that it calls. Example:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::function<void()>> proxy1_callbacks;
extern "C" // probably
void proxy1(void*) {
    for(auto&& func : proxy1_callbacks) func();
}

void my_register_callback(std::function<void()> callback) {
    proxy1_callbacks.emplace_back(std::move(callback));
    external_register_callback(proxy1);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ocrvfEnj3)

---

In the event `external_register_callback` actually takes a `void*` argument too

```cpp
void external_register_callback(callback_type callback, void* userdata) {
    //...
}
```

which is then supplied to the callback function when that is called (which is very common), you could use that `void*` to point at your `std::function<void()>`.

```cpp
void my_register_callback(std::function<void()> callback) {
    // store the callbacks somewhere else if you need the capability
    // to unregister them later
    static std::list<std::function<void()>> lookup;

    // store the callback and get a pointer to it
    void* ptr = &lookup.emplace_back(std::move(callback));

    external_register_callback(
        [](void* userdata) {
            // cast back and call
            (*static_cast<std::function<void()>*>(userdata))();
        },
        ptr); // the pointer to your std::function<void()>
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1zWKrqzcv)

---

Instead of having a separate `my_register_callback` function, you could also make your classes register to the C style callback framework to call specific event handlers on the object that has registered.

Say you have a few different C style registering functions for the API you are using:

```c
void register_callback_x(callback_type callback, void* userdata) {}
void register_callback_y(callback_type callback, void* userdata) {}
```

You could then create instances of a class that registers `static` member functions. In those, you cast back to the `class` type and call the (non-`static`) target member function.

```cpp
class callback_handler {
public:
    callback_handler() {
        register_callback_x(on_x_proxy, this);
        register_callback_y(on_y_proxy, this);
    }
    ~callback_handler() {
        // unregister
    }
    void on_x() {
        // called on a specific object
    }
    void on_y() {
        // called on a specific object
    }

private:
    // proxies that cast userdata to class type and calls the 
    // non-static callback function
    static void on_x_proxy(void* userdata) {
        static_cast<callback_handler*>(userdata)->on_x();
    }
    static void on_y_proxy(void* userdata) {
        static_cast<callback_handler*>(userdata)->on_y();
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G78rexeac)

and if you want different classes to be able to register, you could use polymorphism. Either you use run-time polymorphism by making `on_x`/`on_y` `virtual` or you could do it at compile-time using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Here's a CRTP example:

```cpp
template<class T>
class handler_base {
protected:
    handler_base() {
        register_callback_x(on_x_proxy, this);
        register_callback_y(on_y_proxy, this);
    }
    ~handler_base() {
        // unregister
    }
    
private:
    static void on_x_proxy(void* userdata) {
        static_cast<T*>(userdata)->on_x();
    }
    static void on_y_proxy(void* userdata) {
        static_cast<T*>(userdata)->on_y();
    }
};
```

```cpp
class callback_handler_1 : handler_base<callback_handler> {
public:
    void on_x() {}
    void on_y() {}
};

class callback_handler_2 : handler_base<callback_handler> {
public:
    void on_x() {}
    void on_y() {}
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W9MsY5x3j)

Comment: the functions are called by some legacy code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, probably a C api. Shouldn't be a problem though since that API calls `proxy1`.

Comment: oh now I get it :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does not seem as straight forward as the solution @Guillaume Racicot posted, is there any benefit to it?

Comment: @Johannes You're welcome. There are now tree versions in the answer where the second and third version fits your updated question where the third is what I usually use myself. I'm not sure how it compares to Guillaume's solution. I didn't look into how that works.

Comment: @Johannes I added a fourth version in case you want to reuse the registering/unregistering pattern for different classes.

Answer (score 3):

There's a common pattern for this, when you want to snd any callback type to a c library. This is not about dropping the parameter, but about putting your own callback in the context.

Let's imagine for the sake of simplicity that we don't need to worry about lifetimes.

The pattern consist of taking the callback as an object with a working call syntax. It could be a function pointer, a lambda or a `std::function`. You set the `void*` to point to it, and you send in a function pointer that takes the context and convert it back to the function object to call it.

It goes like this:

```
template<std::invocable<> F>
void my_register_callback(F& callback) {
    set_context(&callback); // sets the void*
    external_register_callback([](void* context) {
        // Retrieve the callback
        F* callback = static_cast<F*>(context);

        // Call it!
        (*callback)();
    });
}
```

This allows to set any callback to the c library, including function object, pointer to function, lambdas or another polymorphic wrapper like `std::function`.

Keep in mind that with this pattern, you can completely skip the double indirection that a `std::function` would occur.

This pattern works because lambdas without captures are convertible to a function pointer.

As a bonus, you also do not rely on a global object to make that call work with the C library.

---

Now for lifetimes, I would say, you can definitely manage the lifetime of the function object inside your wrapper layer, and keep it alive for as much time as you need, preferably until you unset the callback.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I changed `my_register_callback` so it takes `F callback` by value, otherwise I was not able to directly pass lambdas (without storing them somewhere). Is there any drawback to that?

Comment: @Johannes Yes. The lambda dies when the function ends. If you take by value you must copy it in a storage. That storage can be a std::function, it can be the heap + deleter it just some kind of container in your layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the `void*` the function receives, you should have it point to the `std::function<void()>` instance you want to be called and then invoke it inside your custom callback:

```
void my_callback(void* p) {
   const auto f = static_cast<std::function<void()>*>(p);
   if (f) {
      (*f)();
   }
}
```

Otherwise, you need a global instance your callback can dispatch from:

```
thread_local std::function<void()> f;

void my_callback(void* p) {
   if (f) {
      f();
   }
}
```